# split string by dot+colon

Tags: r, regex

is there any way to split string by ".:" ?

```
string = "DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1"
strsplit( x = string,split = ".:" ) # didn't work
strsplit( x = string,split = "\\.:" ) # didn't work
strsplit( x = string,split = "\\.\\:" ) # didn't work
```

Comment: I think `"\\\.:"` will work.

Comment: Please describe *didn't work*. Errors? Undesired results? No split?

Comment: There is no `.:` in your string. Notice the space between the dot and colon.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik heck you are right. I feel stupid now. sry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a workaround:

With `str_extract` and the regex `'(?<=:)[^.]+'` lookaround we match substring `((?<=:))` that precedes before any character that are not a `.`  with regex `([^.]+)`

With `str_replace` we make use of `string2` and replace it by `""`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

string2 <- str_extract(string, '(?<=:)[^.]+')
string1 <- str_replace(string, string2, '')
```

output:

```
> string2 <- str_extract(string, '(?<=:)[^.]+')
> string1 <- str_replace(string, string2, '')
> string1
[1] "DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . :"
> string2
[1] " fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1"
```

Answer (score 2):

Or in `base R` with `strsplit`

```
 strsplit(string, "(?<=:)\\s+", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
```